# javascript conditional statement using &&

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, conditional-statements

I am attempting to change the state of a button if all of three specific elements have a specific class applied.

Previously I was simply counting the number of li's with the class "complete" but now I need to be more specific.

```
$("#signUp li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("complete");
    //    if($("#signUp li.complete").length >= 3){

        if(  $ ( "#signUp li:first-child" && "#signUp li:nth-child(5)" && "#signUp li:nth-child(7)" ).hasClass( "complete" ) )
        {
        $("#done").addClass("active");
        };
    });
```

I've tried this and some variations thereof but the best result has been to meet the criteria when the last li's class is set to "complete"

I've been poking around a bit but couldn't find a specific instance that matches my situation.

Always thanks for awesome responses that educate and correct my amateur ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Jquery selector is invalid, what you actually need to do is this:

```
$("#signUp li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("complete");

    if(
        $("#signUp li:first-child").hasClass("complete") &&
        $("#signUp li:nth-child(5)").hasClass("complete") &&
        $("#signUp li:nth-child(7)").hasClass("complete"))
    {
        $("#done").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Your current code runs only when the last selector has the class because the strings are being evaluated as a boolean operation. This means that the following is performed:

```
"#signUp li:first-child" && "#signUp li:nth-child(5)" && "#signUp li:nth-child(7)"
```

When this evaluates true (which it always does, because non-empty strings are "[truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)"), it simply returns the last evaluated value, which would be `"#signUp li:nth-child(7)"`, so your whole statement was getting compiled into:

```
if($("#signUp li:nth-child(7)").hasClass("complete")) {
        $("#done").addClass("active");
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that explains it, I had tried that but without the "$" before each challenge.

Comment: which would be "#signUp li:nth-child(7)" this is incorrect as well... no statement is ever run. the whole string will be evaluated first. this is literally pass true to jquery.

Comment: @aepheus - JavaScript will return the last evaluated value in an AND statement when all values are truthy. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4zdBk/2/.

Comment: Here's a nice list of basic logical AND/OR statements and their corresponding return values: http://jsfiddle.net/txxnk/2/ ... JavaScript is a weird language.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply stating it like this:

```
        if( $("#signUp li:first-child").hasClass("complete")
              && $("#signUp li:nth-child(5)").hasClass("complete")
              && $("#signUp li:nth-child(7)").hasClass("complete") ){
          ... code
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
if(  $ ( "#signUp li:first-child" && "#signUp li:nth-child(5)" && "#signUp li:nth-child(7)" ).hasClass( "complete" ) )
```

should be this (improved):

```
if(  $ ( "#signUp").find("li:first-child:not(.complete), li:nth-child(5):not(.complete), li:nth-child(7):not(.complete)" ).length == 3 )
```

"#signUp li:first-child" && "#signUp li:nth-child(5)" && "#signUp li:nth-child(7)"

evaluates to true, as && is a logic operator. so you are really doing $(true).hasClass(...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `not` selector to find out if any are not complete.

http://jsfiddle.net/

```
if ($("li:not(.complete)").length == 0) {}
```

Comment: this does not have the same meaning.

Comment: @aepheus - I would argue that it is certainly workable, easier to understand and easier to maintain. Instead of having to add more and more `&&` as form requirements change he could leverage multiple classes, for example `complete` and `required`.

Comment: I would agree that it is workable. But you have to think about a case where the function should execute given only 1, 5, and 7 are complete. This code would incorrectly disallow execution if 2,3,4, or 6 are complete, but 1, 5, 7 are not.

Comment: True - I had assumed that the poster was capable of making the mental leap. I could have been more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that isn't right, you're doing an && operation on strings which won't give the results you expect. The following however, will work.

```
$ ( "#signUp li:first-child" ).hasClass("complete") 
    && $( "#signup li:nth-child(5)" ).hasClass("complete") 
    && $("#signup li:nth-child(7)" ).hasClass( "complete" )
```

Comment: Actually no, that would be a union instead of an intersection. Ignore this answer, go with everybody elses.

Comment: this will evaluate to true if any of those have the class completed. also, the #signUp would need to precede each li.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just realizing that now. Probably should have tested this before posting.